# PHP: how can I pass a hidden variable to one page while using a submit button to direct the user to another page?

Tags: php, string, forms, hidden-field

I am looking to get the string variable to go to one page, new user page, while the user is directed to page 8.

```
</p>
<form method="GET" action="pg8.php">
<! moving variables to text file-->
<input name="input1" type="hidden" <?php echo "value=$i1" ?> >
<input name="submit1" type="hidden" <?php echo "value=$f"?> >
<input name="submit2" type="hidden" <?php echo "value=$t"?> >
<input name="submit3" type="hidden" <?php echo "value=$fa"?> >
<input name="submit4" type="hidden" <?php echo "value=$c"?> >
<input type="submit" name="submituser" value="continue">

<?php $string="$string.{$i1}.{$f}.{$t}.{$fa}.{$c}";?>
<input type="hidden" name="newuser" value=<?php echo "$string" ?> >
</form>
```

Comment: Why do you even need such a thing? You may consider using AJAX but if you could explain your main purpose in doing this, you may get better advice.

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript for that. On submit, send data via ajax to first page. Instantly after that refer via window.location=secondpage.php to second page.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a redirect on the first stop to send the user to **page 8** after you've dealt with the form?

You could accomplish this with `header()`.

**one_page.php**

```
// deal with the form
$_GET['some_field'];

// after you're done, send the user to page 8
header('Location: pg8.php');
exit(); // to prevent from executing anything else before the redirect
```

And in the form, just change

```
<form method="GET" action="one_page.php">
```

This would yield the best result IMO.

### Scheme of redirects

1. The user fills out a form on `form.php` and clicks the submit button
2. Then the user is sent to what the form action is, say `form_logic.php`
3. Inside `form_logic.php` after some calculations, the user is sent off to the final page of this form submission, say `form_result.php`

This all happens very quickly and from the users perspective (depending on the amount of work you do in `form_logic.php`) it appears that he was sent directly to `form_result.php`.

Comment: how does this work out syntactically? as in, where does exit go in relation to form code above? thx, we agree this is much better than other options such as, ajax or mySql, not in need of quite so much infrastructure.

Comment: What do you mean by that? Instead of two files, you make 3, one displays the form, the second `one_page.php` deals with the form, and then redirects the user (without displaying anything, just doing some magic on the server) to `pg8.php` or whatever else you wnat.

Comment: @user2422866 I've updated my answer to explain this scheme, is this what you wanted to know? :)